# configurar emails en digitalocean para varios dominios

Tags: email, symfony3, virtualhost, digitalocean

Necesito enviar y recibir emails para varios dominios en un VPS de digitalocean. No logro encontrar la configuración correcta para que los emails salgan con email1@dominio.com para cada dominio y se puedan recibir emails a la misma cuenta (aunque la cuenta no exista).
He seguido tutoriales de digitalocean para configurar postfix pero no puedo resolver como configurar un FQDN para el Droplet y mantener las virtual host para cada sitio ademas.

Por si sirve aclarar, los sitios que están actualmente en funcionamiento ya fueron apuntados a los servidores de digitalocean y están desarrollados en symfony3.

Answer (score 0):

Las webs entiendo serán gestionadas probablemente con Nginx o Apache + PHP.

El servicio de correo no tiene nada que ver los sitios web en sí, puede poner la configuración del main.cf

En http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html tienes algunos ejemplos de configuración de POSTFIX que te podrán ayudar

Comment: Las webs tienen cada una una virtualhost gestionada por Apache. Mi problema es que localmente puedo enviar emails con swiftmailer desde mi pc, pero desde los servidores de digitalocean no. Verifique el puerto 25, 587 y estan habilitados. Luego logre que envien emails con sendgrid.net por medio de SMTP pero no puedo crear webmails con sendgrid.

Comment: La verdad me tiene mareado este tema de los servicios mail y no entiendo como configurarlo, cual seria la mejor manera de lograr lo que necesito y poder enviar y recibir mails desde info@midominio1.com o ventas@midominio2.com.ar por ejemplo. Así como recibir respuestas a esos mails, poder enviar mails de marketing a traves de los mismos. Me explico a lo que quiero llegar?

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con tu configuración de POSTFIX que puedes encontrar en /etc/postfix/main.cf  y lo reviso pon tambien los logs de mail.err y mail.debug